# Why is my parallel foreach loop implementation slower than the single-threaded one?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to implement the parallel foreach loop for `std::vector` which runs the computations in optimal number of threads (number of cores minus 1 for main thread), however, my implementation seems to be not fast enough – it actually runs *6 times slower* than the single-threaded one!

The thread instantiation is often blamed for being a bottleneck so I tried a larger vector, however, that did not seem to help.

I am currently stuck watching the parallel algorithm executed in 13000-20000 microseconds in a separate thread while single-threaded one is executed in 120-200 microseconds in the main thread and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Out of those 13-20 ms parallel algorithm runs for 8 or 9 are usually utilized to create thread, however, I can still see no reason for `std::for_each` running through 1/3 of the vector in a separate thread for several times longer than another `std::for_each` need to iterate through the whole vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

const unsigned int numCores = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

const size_t numUse = numCores - 1;

struct foreach
{
    inline static void go(std::function<void(uint32_t&)>&& func, std::vector<uint32_t>& cont)
    {
        std::vector<std::thread> vec;
        vec.reserve(numUse);
        std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t>::iterator> arr(numUse + 1);
        size_t distance = cont.size() / numUse;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < numUse; i++)
            arr[i] = cont.begin() + i * distance;
        arr[numUse] = cont.end();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < numUse - 1; i++)
        {
            vec.emplace_back([&] { std::for_each(cont.begin() + i * distance, cont.begin() + (i + 1) * distance, func); });
        }
        vec.emplace_back([&] { std::for_each(cont.begin() + (numUse - 1) * distance, cont.end(), func); });
        for (auto &d : vec)
        {
            d.join();
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock clock;
    std::vector<uint32_t> numbers;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 50000000; i++)
        numbers.push_back(i);
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t0m = clock.now();
    std::for_each(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [](uint32_t& value) { ++value; });

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1m = clock.now();
    std::cout << "Single-threaded run executes in " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t1m - t0m).count() << "mcs\n";
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t0s = clock.now();
    foreach::go([](uint32_t& i) { ++i; }, numbers);

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1s = clock.now();
    std::cout << "Multi-threaded run executes in " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t1s - t0s).count() << "mcs\n";
    getchar();
}
```

Is there a way I can optimize this and increase the performance?

The compiler I am using is Visual Studio 2017's one. Config is Release x86. I have also been advised to use a profiler and am currently figuring out how to use one.

I actually managed to get parallel code run faster than the regular one, however, this required vector of dozens of thousands of vectors of five elements. If anyone has advices on how to improve performance or where can I find better implementation to check its structure, that would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you compiling this? What compiler and what flags are you using? I would advise against printing within a timed block of code during benchmarks.

Comment: The work you do in each thread is not that much. The cost of creating threads is probably larger than the work done.

Comment: @III Perhaps you might be able to answer this?

Comment: @François Andrieux I am using Visual Studio 2017 along with c++14 version and no optimizations enabled. I have only printed the time before and after computations originally, however, as I checked the time used for threads creation I figured out they take way less time than the thread work itself and decided to include the printing code

Comment: @NickM It's important to benchmark with optimizations turned up. Otherwise you are including delays from abstractions that won't actually slow down your release build and from debugging tools built into the standard library.

Comment: ***and no optimizations enabled*** You need to fix that. Timing a debug build is not valuable. I have seen cases where a debug build in Visual Studio was 100 times slower than release (yes a few seconds to over a day).

Comment: @François Andrieux With the /02 optimizations (Release x86 config) the single-thread vs multi-thread performance is 147 vs 13000 microseconds. Thread creation is now taking much bigger chunk of time, however, threads are joning in 3 ms which has no sense if I wish to improve performance compared to the single-core version

Comment: @NickM Visual Studio's performance profiler pretty good. It should tell you what part of your code is slow.

Comment: @NickM Note that if your first case became excessively faster, it may be that the whole test was optimized out entirely since the result doesn't matter and is never used.

Comment: @François Andrieux I have tried adding the cycles for incrementing each element between the measurements and printing random elements from the vector where counter increases by rand() % 2000 (I may be wrong, but I suppose this should keep compiler from optimizing the functions out) and the results are pretty same – 200 mcs for single-threaded vs 20000 mcs for multi-threaded computations.

I have never ever used a profiler, so this may turn up to being time-consuming and hopefully someone shows up with an answer while I am learning how to use one

Comment: @NickM Visual Studio has an Analyze item in the menu bar and it should contain Performance Profiller. I think the shortcut is Alt + F2. Check the CPU usage checkbox, select release build and click Start. VS makes it incredibly easy.

Comment: @François Andrieux thank you for the guidance on how to run it, Internet seems to offer standalone profilers. I did that and ended up with a lot of percentages over there from which I was able to figure out that lambda parameter for ```vec.emplace_back``` takes 13% CPU time and ```std::for_each``` inside it takes 12% of the CPU time. I am not quite sure what to do next from here – I do not think I can optimize ```std``` functions :(

Comment: @NickM But you can optimize how those functions and features are used. For example it may be that there are excessive copies being made. It's hard to say exactly what the issue is. At least you learned a valuable skill today.

Comment: @NickM When I try your code, removing the `std::cout` more than doubles your implementation's speed. And by increasing the number of elements, your implementation becomes better. At `50000000` elements (100x what you tried) I get 10% faster execution with your parallel implementation. This is likely because there is so much flat overhead with starting threads and setting up your solution. It's only worth it when the the quantity of work to be done is large enough that the gains from parallelization outweigh the overhead.

Comment: @François Andrieux Please let me know which compiler you use.
As I remove the ```std::cout```s inside the function performance in multi-threaded run is still 2x worse than the single-threaded one, no matter how I play with the parameter types (&, &&) so that is still an issue for me, sorry to bother you

Comment: Vs2015 with default compiler. It may be a system performance difference.

Comment: @François Andrieux I managed to figure out that the algorithm performs like 2x faster than the single-threaded one if i load it heavily (operating vector of 5000000 vectors of five), however, that is as can be clearly guessed not the performance improvement that can please one. Thank you for your help man.

Comment: Modern cpu's with Optimize cranked to max use allot of special vector Instructions that are simply native to x86.
A compiler can sometimes use OPcodes that boil down to adding 32 ints to 32 other ints in ONE instruction
Have a look at https://godbolt.org/ just to see what your code compiles to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for providing some example code.

Getting good metrics (especially on parallel code) can be pretty tricky. Your metrics are tainted.

1. Use `high_resolution_clock` instead of `steady_clock` for profiling.
2. Don't include the thread startup time in your timing measurement. Thread launch/join is orders of magnitude longer than your actual work here. You should create the threads once and use condition variables to make them sleep until you signal them to work. This is not trivial, but it is essential that you don't measure the thread startup time.
3. Visual Studio has a profiler. You need to compile your code with release optimizations but also include the debug symbols (those are excluded in the default release configuration). I haven't looked into how to set this up manually because I usually use CMake and it sets up a RelWithDebInfo configuration automatically.

Another issue kind of related to having good metrics is that your "work" is just incrementing an integer. Is that really representative of the work your program is going to be doing? Increment is really fast. If you look at the assembly generated by your sequential version, everything gets inlined into a really short loop.

Lambdas have a very good chance of being inlined. But in your `go` function, you're casting the lambda to `std::function`. `std::function` has a very poor chance of being inlined.
So if you want to keep the chance of getting the lambda inlined, you have to do some template tricks:

```
template <typename FUNC>
inline static void go(FUNC&& func, std::vector<uint32_t>& cont)
```

By manually inlining your code (I moved the contents of the `go` function to `main`) and doing step 2 above, I was able to get the parallel version (4 threads on a hyperthreaded dual-core) to run in about 75% of the time. That's not particularly good scaling, but it's not bad considering that the original was already pretty fast. For a further optimization, I would use SIMD aka "vector" (different from `std::vector` except in the sense that they both relate to arrays) operations which will apply the increment to multiple array elements in one iteration.

You have a race condition here:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < numUse - 1; i++)
{
    vec.emplace_back([&] { std::for_each(cont.begin() + i * distance, cont.begin() + (i + 1) * distance, func); });
}
```

because you set the default lambda capture to capture-by-reference, the `i` variable is a reference and that could cause some threads to check the wrong range or too long of a range. You could do this: `[&, i]`, but why risk shooting yourself in the foot again? Scott Meyers recommends against using default capture modes. Just do `[&cont, &distance, &func, i]`

**UPDATE:**

I think it's a fine idea to move your `foreach` to its own space. I think what you should do is separate the thread creation from task dispatch. That means you need some kind of signaling system (generally condition variables). You could look into thread pools.

An easy way to add threadpools is to use OpenMP, which Visual Studio 2017 has support for (OpenMP 2.0). A caveat is that there's no guarantee that the threads won't be created/destroyed during entry/exit of the parallel section (it's implementation dependent). So it trades off performance with ease of use.

If you can use C++17, it has a standard parallel `for_each` (the `ExecutionPolicy` overload). Most of the algorithmy standards functions do. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each

As for using `std::function` you can use it, you just don't want your basic operation (the one that will be called 50,000,000 times) to be a `std::function`.

Bad:

```
void go(std::function<...>& func)
{
    std::thread t(std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), func));
    ...
}

...
go([](int& i) { ++i; });
```

Good:

```
void go(std::function<...>& func)
{
    std::thread t(func);
    ...
}

...
go([&v](){ std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int& i) { ++i; })});
```

In the good version, the short inner lambda (i.e. ++i) gets inlined in the call to for_each. That's important because it gets called 50 million times. The call to the bigger lambda is not inlined (because it's converted to `std::function`) but that's ok because it only gets called once per thread.

Comment: Unfortunately, the increment operation is not quite representative here as the function is intended to be used for any element transformation hence I use lambdas. 

The conditional variables idea is interesting, however, I wish that the ```foreach::go``` can be moved to a separate namespace (e.g. ```parallel```) as a single struct-static function and it doesn't seem to be possible when using the conditional variables. 

As for the std::function, the whole idea of using it was that it allows for using 1 less template parameter if I use it with the appropriate signature.

Comment: Basically, ```foreach``` is a template structure and what I posted here is a ```uint32_t``` specialization. Please let me know if there is a way I can still not use the third template parameter (1 for the value type and 1 for the container type without one for the lambda) and have a good chance it is inlined.  Other than that, kindly thank you for pointing out the race condition for me, I thought on that and can now see why it is caused

Comment: Also, how do I call the function with the lambda type? It is not deduced as far as I can see and the only way I can specify the type is using ```<std::function>```

Comment: It's more or less a good thing that the increment is not representative, since you'll probably see better performance scaling with more complicated operations. You can call the lambda as if it were a function. I messed up the syntax (should be `template <typename FUNC>` not `template <typename FUNC&& func>`). I fixed that and added an update section to respond to these questions :)

Comment: Thank you for the update on the matter! It turned out as a surprise for me that the C++17 has implemented parallel for_each, more than that, I have figured out it is 1.5 times faster than my implementation. Well, at least I was having fun writing these! Thank you for the recommendations on the std::function. As for the thread pooling/cond variables, please correct me if I am wrong, I suppose the std::for_each runs those without this 2-step initialization-separate-from-execution approach. How do they reach such a performance, if that does not bother you very much to explain?

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned parallel `for_each` sooner. How they organize the thread pooling...I don't know! The implementations in various compilers' libraries are relatively recent and to be honest, I haven't tried them yet. I think it's safe to assume it's no worse than OpenMP, but it could depend not just on the compiler but also a particular algorithm. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/09/11/using-c17-parallel-algorithms-for-better-performance/